# Remove backslashes from JSON SQL Query

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

I am constructing JSON object using SQL Server query. I have issues with slashes and also i need data in specific format as mentioned below. The actual output has slashes in it. I want to eliminate slashes from my output query.

```
    SELECT (SELECT 
         ('{'+'"value":'+ cast(ISNULL(SP.ACCOUNT_TRAFFIC_DEP_LICENSE_NUMBER,'') as varchar) )                       AS TRAFFIC_DEP_LICENSE_NUMBER
        ,(  '{' +'"value":'+cast(ISNULL(SP.NUMBER_OF_VEHICLES   ,'')    as varchar)     )                                   AS NUMBER_OF_VEHICLES
         ,( '{' +'"value":'+cast(ISNULL(SP.ACCOUNT_TRAFFIC_DEP_LICENSE_START_H_DATE,'') as varchar) )                                       AS TRAFFIC_DEP_LICENSE_START_H_DATE
         ,( '{' +'"value":'+cast(ISNULL(SP.ACCOUNT_TRAFFIC_DEP_LICENSE_END_H_DATE   ,'')    as varchar)     )                           AS TRAFFIC_DEP_LICENSE_END_H_DATE
        ,(  '{' +'"value":'+cast(ISNULL(SP.SUSPENSION_BY_MORROR_STATUS,'')  as varchar)         )                                           AS SUSPENSION_BY_MORROR_STATUS
         ,( '{' +'"value":'+cast(ISNULL(SP.SUSPENSION_BY_VIOLATION  ,'')    as varchar)     )                                           AS SUSPENSION_BY_VIOLATION
         ,( '{' +'"value":'+cast(ISNULL(SP.SUSPENSION_BY_PENALTY        ,'')    as varchar)     )                                           AS SUSPENSION_BY_PENALTY
                from [dbo].[TAMM_CAC_ACCOUNTS_STG]  SP 
                where SP.Account_Reference_Number = CAC.Account_Reference_Number
                AND (
                ACCOUNT_TRAFFIC_DEP_LICENSE_NUMBER IS NOT NULL OR 
                NUMBER_OF_VEHICLES IS NOT NULL OR
                SP.ACCOUNT_TRAFFIC_DEP_LICENSE_END_H_DATE   IS NOT NULL OR
                SP.ACCOUNT_TRAFFIC_DEP_LICENSE_END_H_DATE   IS NOT NULL OR
                SP.SUSPENSION_BY_MORROR_STATUS              IS NOT NULL OR
                SP.SUSPENSION_BY_VIOLATION          IS NOT NULL OR      
                SP.SUSPENSION_BY_PENALTY        IS NOT NULL     )   FOR JSON PATH,INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES

 
 ) AS specifics
            from dbo.Customer_Account CAC
```

The above query gives me desired output but It has backslashes.

```
[
  {
    "TRAFFIC_DEP_LICENSE_NUMBER": "{\"value\":0",
    "NUMBER_OF_VEHICLES": "{\"value\":1009",
    "TRAFFIC_DEP_LICENSE_START_H_DATE": "{\"value\":14351229",
    "TRAFFIC_DEP_LICENSE_END_H_DATE": "{\"value\":14351229",
    "SUSPENSION_BY_MORROR_STATUS": "{\"value\":0",
    "SUSPENSION_BY_VIOLATION": "{\"value\":1",
    "SUSPENSION_BY_PENALTY": "{\"value\":1"
  }
]
```

actual expected output is below

```
{
"specific": {
    "TRAFFIC_DEP_LICENSE_NUMBER": {"value": 0},
    "NUMBER_OF_VEHICLES": {"value": 22},
    "TRAFFIC_DEP_LICENSE_START_H_DATE": {"value": 14480608},
    "TRAFFIC_DEP_LICENSE_END_H_DATE": {"value": 14480608},
    "SUSPENSION_BY_MORROR_STATUS": {"value": 0},
    "SUSPENSION_BY_VIOLATION": {"value": 1},
    "SUSPENSION_BY_PENALTY": {"value": 1}
}
```

Comment: I would it expect it to have backslashes. the value inside you're passing to your JSOPN is `"value"`. When you put that in the JSON (which needs to be quoted), it turns into `"\"value\""`, as the double quotes within the value need to be escaped. Can you post us some sample data please?

Comment: Re: `cast(... as varchar)` please read [this post](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

Answer (score 14):

If I understand your question correctly and you want to remove escaping of the special characters to generate a valid JSON content, next solution may help.

`FOR JSON` clause [escapes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/how-for-json-escapes-special-characters-and-control-characters-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#escaping-of-special-characters) special characters in the `JSON` output with `\`.

> ... If the source data contains special characters, the FOR JSON
>   clause escapes them in the JSON output with \, as shown in the
>   following table. This escaping occurs both in the names of properties
>   and in their values. ...

If you are sure, that you generate a valid `JSON`, you may try to use [JSON_QUERY with FOR JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#using-json_query-with-for-json).

> ... JSON_QUERY returns a valid JSON fragment. As a result, FOR JSON
>   doesn't escape special characters in the JSON_QUERY return value.  ...

Simple example, that demonstrates your issue:

```
-- Statement:
SELECT (
   SELECT '{"value": 1}' AS TRAFFIC_DEP_LICENSE_NUMBER
   FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
) AS specifics

-- Output:
-------------------------------------------------
specifics
-------------------------------------------------
[{"TRAFFIC_DEP_LICENSE_NUMBER":"{\"value\": 1}"}]
```

Solution:

```
-- Statement:
SELECT (
   SELECT JSON_QUERY('{"value": 1}') AS TRAFFIC_DEP_LICENSE_NUMBER
   FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
) AS specifics

-- Output:
-------------------------------------------------
specifics
-------------------------------------------------
[{"TRAFFIC_DEP_LICENSE_NUMBER":{"value": 1}}]
```

Notes:

You may check your JSON using [ISJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT (
   SELECT CASE
      WHEN ISJSON('{"value": 1}') = 1 THEN JSON_QUERY('{"value": 1}') 
      ELSE 'Invalid JSON'
   END AS TRAFFIC_DEP_LICENSE_NUMBER
   FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
) AS specifics
```